# squash several commits on branch

Tags: git, github

I want to squash the last 7  commits to 1 commit for specific branch (all the commits were on the same branch `the_branch` ) and 
before doing that I want to verify that these are the needed steps

```
git rebase -i HEAD~7
git commit -m “new commit”
git push origin the_branch
```

Are these the necessary steps or should I add something ?

[Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/37268543#37268543)

Comment: After choosing to interactively rebase last 7 commits, you have to choose what to do with them (pick, delete, squash, ...). There is one step missing in your approach. What did you choose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: As a general piece of advice, don't try queuing up multiple commands like this. Do the rebase+squash and then check what state you're in before deciding what to do next. Many of the problems I see people having with git stem from them pasting commands without knowing their initial state, and not reading the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes the answer you are referring to is correct, the steps you are proposing to do are not correct:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~7
```

now you need to change the first word of all lines except the first one from pick to squash

after this you **don't** need to create a new commit.

If you had pushed your branch before the squashing of the commits, you will however need to **force** push your branch since you rewrote history

```
git push --force-with-lease origin the_branch
```

If you had not pushed before, normal push will suffice:

```
git push origin the_branch
```

Comment: The force is only necessary if the previous HEAD had been pushed. If you were 7 commits ahead of origin in the first place, no force is required.

Comment: Thanks, should I use it this "git push --force-with-lease origin the_branch" as is ?

Comment: When I run `git rebase -i HEAD~6` I got list of the commits with texts? what should I do now?

Comment: from my answer: `# now you need to change the first word of all lines except the first one from pick to squash`

Answer (score 3):

I think it's easier to use `git reset` with the `soft` option.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~7
```

If you are not sure about the `HEAD~7`, do `git log --oneline`, copy de hash of the 8th commit, and:

```
git reset --soft <hash_your_commit>
```

Now, all your files you have modified during the last 7 commits are in the staging area and ready for commit:

```
git commit -m "7 commits squashed into 1"
```

Finally, to that commit to the `remote`, you'll have to use the `-f` or `--force` option if one or more of the 7 commits were already on the `remote`. That way, those commits will disappear from the `remote` as well.

```
// if none of the 7 commits are on the remote
git push origin branch
//else
git push -f origin branch
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do a soft reset and live happily ever after:

```
git checkout --detach
git reset --soft HEAD~7 # move branch pointer 7 revisions back, _DO NOT_ tough my working tree.... all changes between HEAD~7 and the tip of the branch are saved in index, ready to be committed
git commit -m "Blah blah"
# if you like the result
git branch -f my-branch
git checkout my-branch
git push -f origin my-branch # force-push as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

- git rebase from the master
- `git fetch` and `git log` are just to make sure you are updated and you can see the log to make sure your rebase worked correctly.
- after you do a `git rebase -i origin/master` in the vi editor use the option fixup to squash all commits which you don't want [image]
- If there are any conflicts use `git add .` and `git rebase --continue` otherwise you can ignore this step.
- Just check logs to make sure your commits are at correct place using `git log` this step is not needed its optional.
- Lastly you need do a force push using `git push -f`

  ```
  git fetch
  git log
  git rebase -i origin/master
  git status
  git add .
  git rebase --continue
  git log
  git push -f
  ```

Comment: It isn't possible to list the exact commands OP needs to execute because it depends on his situation. For instance, your commands rebase on top of master, whereas OP wants to rebase the last 7 commits on his branch. Given that situation, it is unlikely rebasing will stop and thus the add and continue part of your commands are unlikely to be needed. Additionally, there might be good reasons why a pre-push hook wants to prevent the push, uncritically suggesting to use `--no-verify` can be harmful.

Comment: after it open the vim ui I got 5 commits that I want and one I don’t want , should I mark all I want
with s and the one that I don’t want with d ? after then should I click `esc` ?  and then push it ?

Comment: @JennyM option drop will remove the commit and squash will meld your existing commit into the previous commit note that this will open a new view which will show you the 2 commit messages and would ask you to either give your preference of message. Even if you don't do any thing here and just esc and write changes (using esc  :x ) you will see your squashed commit is meld into the previous with message shown as a sub part of the previous message
To save and exit a vi editor just esc and :x would do